# How do I shrink my div since negative padding isn't possible? How do I centralize it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website to test my knowledge on. Right now I'm trying to make a "logo" on the top center of the site but I'm having problems making the text where I want it to be, and a huge problem with the div surrounding the logo text.

```css
:root {
  --text-font: "Trebuchet MS";
  --text-color: #5c0a0a;
  --box-color: #de7188;
  --border-color: pink;
}

header {
  font-family: var(--text-font);
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Alex Brush", cursive;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px white;
}

body {
  background: url(Images/Background.jpg);
  background-color: tomato;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: var(--text-font);
}

#logo {
  background-color: var(--box-color);
  border: 0.15em solid var(--border-color);
  border-radius: 5em;
  width: 11em;
}

#motto {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: -2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alex+Brush&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>
      Sitename
    </h1>
    <h2 id="motto">
      Motto Goes Here<br><br>
    </h2>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  <h2>
    Filler
  </h2>
  <p>
    Some filler text that I may replace with something later.
  </p>
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired outcome?

Comment: You haven't really explained how and what you need/want to do other than "shrink my div" - can you clarify?

Comment: I wanna decrease the top and bottom paddings of the logo div, centralize the text in it, and centralize the div itself in the top of the page.

Comment: perhaps removing the `BR` tags after the `H2` might help - they are not required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
#logo{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As for the height, I wouldn't recommend getting space in the bottom using `<br>`, perhaps declaring #motto's height would do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `margin: 0 auto;` did indeed work and so did removing the line breaks. I think I had those for an earlier purpose and didn't realize I forgot them there.
Adding a height to my #motto is what I was looking for, but now I'm facing a problem with the div being stuck to the top of the page. Unsure how to fix it, I've tried `margin-top` in #logo but it didn't work. Thanks again for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Never mind, I think I found the problem. It was in the margins in my `header`. I've fixed it now and the div is no longer stuck to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `margin: 0 auto` to centralize the div horizontally.

Like

```
#logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now you have `h1` tag for your text. Which has some predifined css rule for each browser.

You have to specify media queries and override those rules

```
h1 { // for large screens i.e. desktop, laptop
   margin: 0.67em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { // for the devices of width less than 768px
   h1 {
       margin: 0.3em;
   } 
}
```

And same for `h2` tag

Comment: Thank you. Adding `margin: 0 auto;` did solve the centralization problem, but the rest isn't doing the trick for me. I'm trying to move the #logo div but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried using `margin-top` but it did nothing. The problem is that it's stuck to the top of the page and I need some space there. Thanks again for your time.
Edit: Adding margins to `h1` didn't do anything, at least on my end.

Comment: Never mind, I think I found the problem. It was in the margins in my `header`. I've fixed it now and the div is no longer stuck to the top.